# Monty Hall Problem Wrong Reasoning: By Considering All Possibilities

Tags: probability, monty-hall

Monty Hall Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

Here is a wrong reasoning. I am unable to find the flaw in it.

Given below I have attached three images which give us the three initial possibilities of the items behind the doors. Assume that "C" represents a car, and "G" represents a goat. The three compartments in each rounded rectangle are the three doors. The topmost node of each image represents an initial starting position (which can be seen only by the game show host). The colour in red represents the door chosen. So if "C" is in door number 2, and "C" is in red, then door 2 is chosen by the player. The color in green represents the door that the host chooses to show. If the player does not choose to switch, then the number of possibilities that the player wins are 16 among 32, so the probability that player wins is $\frac{1}{2}$ independent of the startegy! What is incorrect here?

Edit: I am looking for a counting argument for the question (and not a probabilistic argument). At the end the argument should be just like $\frac{no.~of~good~possibilities}{total~no.~of~possibilities}$.

Possibility 1: [image: Possibility 1]

Possibility 2: [image: Possibility 2]

Possibility 3: [image: Possibility 3]

Comment: Probability is not so simple all the time as "number of good possibilities divided by total number of possibilities."  There are two outcomes to playing the lottery: you win or you lose.  The probability of winning the lottery is clearly not $\dfrac{1}{2}$ however.  The possibilities you broke it down into are not equally likely.

Comment: Consider this version of Monty Hall problem: There are $100$ doors with $99$ goats and $1$ car. You pick $1$ out of $100$ doors. Then the host opens $98$ doors with goats, so there is $1$ door you picked and $1$ other door left. Do you still think that you have $50\%$ chance (so there's no need to switch), or will you switch the doors?

Comment: @mowzorn yes this is one of the arguments given widely. But how does this argument violate the argument presented by me?

Comment: @JMoravitz can you create a situation (mapping of Monty hall problem to another problem maybe) where one can easily see it as "number of good possibilities divided by total number of possibilities."? I am used to interpreting probability 'p' as. if the experiment is repeated large no. of times, p fraction will give us the required event. How to look at it in this perspective?

Comment: @mowzorn In fact the application of the (wrong) argument in this question to the case of $100$ doors will result in $100$ "possibility $n$" diagrams with $198$ rounded rectangles in the last row. Altogether there will be $1980$ final possibilities, $990$ good and $990$ bad.

Comment: @AJ The structure of your diagrams implies that in the case where Monty has a choice of which door to open, he chooses a door randomly. This random choice doesn't exist in the other two branches. Looking at your first diagram, if you assume equal probability among the three possibilities in the second row (that is, the player is equally likely to choose door 1 or door 2), you **cannot** have equal probabilities in the last row, because the two possibilities on the left have to add up to the probability of the one possibility they came from. There are at least two ways to fix this ...

Comment: ... one of which is to make Monty choose a door deterministically (resulting in only three possibilities on the last row of each diagram) or introducing a useless random action in the cases where the choice of door is forced, as I suggest [in this answer to a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4489067/139123).

Comment: "if the experiment is repeated large no. of times, p fraction will give us the required event." This does not imply that we were able to partition the outcomes of the experiment into a set of equally-likely cases. What do you say if $p = \sqrt2 - 1$? Could you please edit the question to clarify what you are looking for? Do you want a frequentist explanation ("repeated a large number of times") where $p$ is any number between $0$ and $1,$ or do you want an explanation in which the set of outcomes is partitioned into some number of equally likely cases? These are not the same thing.

Comment: "*can you create a situation where one can easily see it as 'number of good possibilities divided by...*" A somewhat unsatisfying approach: After randomizing the doors, and after you the player choose your first door... have Monty secretly flip a coin *and keep track of the result*.  In the scenarios where there is a choice which door with a goat for Monty to reveal, then reveal the first available such door if Monty flipped a heads, or the second such if flipped a tails.

Comment: In scenarios where there was no choice to be made, just reveal whichever door available... *but still treat coinflip as important!*  In such a manner of organization, you will find that several of your scenarios expand out into *two* outcomes... the one where he flipped heads and the one where he flipped tails, and now these outcomes do happen to be equiprobable as the same type of randomization was available at each random step (*as opposed to randomization in only certain scenarios depending on previously made choices*).

Comment: @JMoravitz That kind of tracking of the coin flip is what I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4489067/139123).

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree that the approach works. But it looks very unnatural to introduce a coin flip! After looking into the probabilistic argument, it looks correct, but to come up with this coin-flip argument in the first attempt is unnatural for some reason!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Using your diagrames:

This is 'Possibility 1'. First, we choose doors randomly with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ (as you can see on the image). Then the host reveals a goat: If we chose doors with car, he can do it in two ways, so there is $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of which door with goat he chooses. In other cases, he has no choice but to pick second doors with goat, hence there is probability $1$. In the last row, you have $4$ scenarios. Let's say that in each of them we switch doors. In the first and second scenario (where we picked car at the start) when we switch we lose: the probability of that is $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3}$. In the third and fourth scenario, when we switch doors we win: the probability of that is $\frac{1}{3}\cdot 1+\frac{1}{3}\cdot 1=\frac{2}{3}$. Notice that the same thing happens in your other two 'Possibilities'. I hope this clears why your argument was wrong: not each scenario has equal 'weight'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason why I have given the (wrong) argument is to avoid probabilities altogether. Is there any way to visualize this without using probability and just using a counting argument?

Comment: It's hard to think about probability without using probability :)

Comment: Then it becomes some kind of recursive definition? :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the two outcomes of winning or losing are not equally likely due to the conditions of the problem. Conditional probability helps avoid this situation, and is what the Monty Hall problem is about.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the problem is that you can't just focus on the possibilities of the bottom of the tree and say they are equally likely to occur. You need to look at the route that was neccesary to take to reach each possibility.

Imagine each node of the tree as a container of liquid, from which at the start all the liquid is in the upper one, and the rows are pipes through which the liquid flows. When you split the upper node (the single of the first row) into three new ones (the possible choices), as they are equally likely, it is as if the same amount of liquid were descending into each of the three lower containers, so that each one receives $1/3$ of what was originally in the upper one.

Now, notice that always one of the containers of the second row has two pipes to two different containers of the third row (the bottom). Each receives $1/2$ of what the parent provided, and as the parent had $1/3$, each ends up having $1/2 * 1/3 = 1/6$.

On the other hand, when a container of the second row only has one pipe to a container of the third row, all the liquid that it had goes down to that other container, which is $1/3$.

So, in the third row you have two containers that have $1/6$ each of the total original liquid, and two containers that have $1/3$ each.

To calculate probabilities by just counting the number of cases without weighing them is an equivalent error to counting money just considering the amount of bills, without taking into account their different denominations (like $\$1$, $\$5$, $\$10$, etc.) If two persons have $10$ bills each, but all of one are of $\$1$ and all of the other are of $\$50$, do they have the same money? It is completely clear that not, and the same occurs with probabilities.